# Xcode: could not load ModelIO.framework, SceneKit.framework, etc

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, xcode10, macos-mojave

Before updating to macOS Mojave my app ran fine without errors, however, I get this error after the update. I have been Googling for 2 days but it seems no one has run into this error yet. **Note:** The app does run as expected. The 3D model file is in the .scn format.

**Buildtime** error:

```
/scntool:-1: Could not load ModelIO.framework ((null))
/scntool:-1: Could not load SceneKit.framework ((null))
/scntool:-1: Could not load PhysicsKit.framework ((null))
/scntool:-1: Could not load Jet.framework ((null))
/scntool:-1: Could not load SpriteKit.framework ((null))
/scntool:-1: The document /Users/salman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JellyFish-fhvcybjymvohlxflnwnxqdepqlrl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/JellyFish.app/art.scnassets/Jellyfish.scn is not an archived scene.
/scntool:-1: Conversion failed, will simply copy input to output.
/scntool:-1: Copy failed file:///Users/salman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JellyFish-fhvcybjymvohlxflnwnxqdepqlrl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/JellyFish.app/art.scnassets/Jellyfish.scn -> file:///Users/salman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JellyFish-fhvcybjymvohlxflnwnxqdepqlrl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/JellyFish.app/art.scnassets/Jellyfish.scn error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "“Jellyfish.scn” couldn’t be copied to “art.scnassets” because an item with the same name already exists." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/salman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JellyFish-fhvcybjymvohlxflnwnxqdepqlrl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/JellyFish.app/art.scnassets/Jellyfish.scn, NSUserStringVariant=(
```

**Edit:** The error has now disappeared without any reason. It's happened before. The error shows up, disappears, then shows up again. Strange.

Comment: Also getting these errors too today

Comment: Same here, error came out of nowhere..

Comment: Just hit this issue as well. Wish I knew what was going on.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @impression7vx no solution yet.

Answer (score 4):

My cause was that the command line tools setting was empty.
I solved by setting Command Line Tools in XCode Menu > Preference > Locations.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to update my computer from 10.13.6 to 10.14 `macOS Mojave` and it required me to install XCode Components. After the completion of that, although I already had XCode 10.1 on my machine, it worked like a charm. It made me reset my active developer path, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-mojave-invalid-active-developer-path, but it works.

If someone comes up with a different solution, I will award it, but currently this is my answer.

Reset your computer -- check for updates -- update -- update XCode -- Finalize.