# SceneKit: imported dae file not copied to app bundle

Tags: xcode, macos, graphics, scenekit

Got a weird scenekit asset problem... I’ve got an assets file (`catalog.scnassets`) that seems to be fine in Xcode. I’ve added to it a `dae` file which also opens fine in Xcode.

However, the file doesn’t seem to get copied into the app bundle when I build (mac app), even though the build logs show it happening:

> copySceneKitAssets: Copy plants.dae
>   copySceneKitAssets: Running scntool on /Users/jason/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirstPersonGame-fxynipfnexmczbgnujwuiqxtiogd/Build/Products/Debug/FirstPersonGame.app/Contents/Resources/catalog.scnassets/plants.dae

When I check that directory in the build folder, `catalog.scnassets` is there, but it’s empty. Any ideas what might be going on?

Here’s what the file looks like in Xcode’s Identity inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It’s simple!

I was seeing a bunch of warnings like:

```
scntool: warning: Could not load ModelIO.framework ((null)) (etc)
```

which led me to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701684/xcode-could-not-load-modelio-framework-scenekit-framework-etc) which solved it for me.

In short: check in Xcode Preferences -> Locations. For me, the “Command Line Tools” had nothing selected (somehow!), so selecting a value there (in my case, Xcode 10.1), then doing a clean build, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Xcode 11.3.1 but command line tools are set. Had to uncheck "prefer compressed textures" to make Xcode import the file. This will also make a json file to show up!?

[image]